# How to connect two PCs with IPv6 addresses

Tags: virtual-machine

I connected two PCs by IPv6 address with same subnet and prefix. These PCs can't ping each other.

Can somebody tell me why these computers can't ping each other?

These are the IP addresses that I assigned:

```
2001:db9:1:1::1/64
2001:db9:1:1::2/64
```

Comment: I left your `virtual-machine` tag because I honestly don't know if you're trying to use virtual machines for that or not. You need to be more specific: Which machines do you connect, how do you connect them (e.g. over a "real" network using a switch, or directly, or as a virtual machine)?

Answer (score 1):

If they're on the same VLAN/subnet (read: no routers or NAT boxes in-between):

- Try pinging them with their link-local IPs (`fe80::` stuff you get automatically)
- Try turning off iptables6 just to make sure you dont have something blocking
- Run tcpdump/Wireshark/tshark on both ends so you know whether the packet leaves the box and arrives on the other

When pinging in IPv6, remember to specify which interface you want the ping go out on.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
ping -6 <IP address>
```

Perhaps you are trying to ping a IPv6 address with an IPv4 ICMP packet.